# Parallelisation in R: Using parLapply with pointer to C object

Tags: c, r, parallel-processing

I'm trying to parallelise an R function that conducts some arithmetic in C.

A C object is constructed once from an R dataset using some function, which I'll call `InitializeCObject`, that returns a pointer to the object.  I want to create an instance of this object on each worker that I can reuse many times.

This is where I've got so far:

```
nCores <- 2
cluster <- makeCluster(nCores)
on.exit(stopCluster(cluster))
clusterEvalQ(cluster, {library(pkgName); NULL})
```

The simplest solution is to make a new C object on each call:

```
x <- list(val1, val2) # list of length `nCores`
parLapply(cluster, x, function (x_i) pkgName::MakeObjectAndCalc(x_i, dataset))
```

But the time spent initializing the C object on every single call outweighs the benefits of parallelization.

I've tried creating `nCores` C objects and exporting all of them to each worker, then making worker `n` use local object `n`:

```
cPointer <- lapply(seq_len(nCores), function(xx) InitializeCObject(dataset))
on.exit(DestroyCObject(cPointer), add=TRUE)
clusterExport(cluster, 'cPointer')
parLapply(cluster, seq_len(nCores), function (i) Calculate(x[[i]], cPointer[[i]]))
```

But this doesn't work; the objects on the workers seem not to be initialized.
So I tried creating a separate C object locally on each worker:

```
clusterExport(cluster, 'dataset')
clusterEvalQ(cluster, {
  localPointer <- InitializeCObject(dataset)
  LocalCalc <- function (x) Calculate(x, localPointer)
  on.exit(DestroyCObject(localPointer))
}
parLapply(cluster, x, LocalCalc)
```

But this causes the workers to crash.  Any suggestions as to how I might move forwards would be appreciated.

---

### edit: minimal C example

Here's my attempt to provide a minimal example of the associated C code.  I'm far from fluent in C structures but hopefully this code is sufficient to demonstrate my problem.

```
// Define object structure
typedef struct CObject_t {
    int data;
} CObject_t *CObject;

// Allocate memory to new (empty) object and return pointer to it
CObject new_object_t(void) {
    CObject new = (CObject)calloc(1, sizeof(CObject_t));
    return new;
}

int initialize_object(const int *dataset, CObject cObj) {
  cObj->data = *dataset;
}

int use_object_to_calculate(int *x, CObject cObj) {
  *x = *x + cObj->data;
  return x;
}
```

Comment: If compiling a C function "outweighs the benefits of parallelization", maybe parallelization is not useful.

Comment: Compiling the C function takes c. 3 seconds but needs to be done once.  My Calculate function takes c. 1 ms but needs to be done billions of times. If parallelizing requires you to compile the C function before every call to Calculate, then that's a major loss.

Comment: Ok I understand. But I don't understand why the compilation would happen for each iteration. I thought it would happen only once per core, at the beginning. Otherwise, you just need to divide your computation in `nCores` blocks explicitly.

Comment: I'm hoping to initialize the cores once, then later on to make many calls to parLapply without having to re-initialize the C object.  Did that answer your question or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal C function so that I can try this?

Comment: I've attempted to abstract the C code I'm using to a minimal form. It's not my code, and as I don't quite understand structures it's not quite compiling. Hopefully it will be enough for you to use?

http://community.dur.ac.uk/martin.smith/src/minimal_example.c
http://community.dur.ac.uk/martin.smith/src/minimal_example.r

Thanks for your help (-:

Comment: By minimal, I meant create one of 5 lines, even if you don't use it.

Comment: I've added a shorter example to the question, hopefully this is more like what you had in mind?

Comment: Really I don't know how to use this. You should really use Rcpp instead of pure C code. This is so much easier.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using an API to someone else's C library, so I don't have control over the C code.  Moreover, performance is a central consideration.  Is Rcpp applicable in such a situation, and if so, can you point me to a good guide for how I might use it to interface with this existing C code?

Comment: Maybe see this for C code: http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=1067. I'm not the best help for this.